# what is the best way to set a property aof a javascript json object by its key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Here are my datas in a fokontanys.json file:

```
{
  "vzdveg643": {
    "lldistrict":"Ambilobe",
    "id_province": 7,
    "id": null
  },
  "vzvsdv5327": {
    "lldistrict":"Ambilobe",
    "id_province": 7,
    "id": null
  }
}
```

I need to replace the "null" value of "id" with the key of each object.
I imported the json file

```
let fokontanys = require("./fokontanys.json");
```

And made a foreach inside of which i made my modifications:

```
Object.keys(fokontanys).forEach(function (fokontany) {    
  fokontanys[fokontany].ll_district=fokontanys[fokontany].lldistrict;
  fokontanys[fokontany].id="????????????????";
  delete fokontanys[fokontany].lldistrict;
  newFokontanys[fokontany] = fokontanys[fokontany];
});
console.log(newFokontanys);
```

Is there any way to get the Key of each object and put it in the id?
I have spent a whole day to find how to do it without any success. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your terminology is wrong and it's making your question unclear. There is no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is a string format. If you have an object, just access it as you normally would. Then you say you want to an "the" Key of each object. A "key" is a term used to describe the "key/value" pairs in an object and your objects have more than one key/value pair. So there is no "the" key. What, exactly, are you trying to do? Can you show what kind of output you are expecting?

Comment: `fokontanys[fokontany].id = fokontany `

Comment: thank you for your answer. what i am trying to achie is to change the id of each object with the value of its key.  i am sorry about the terminology, i am still learning.  here is the object i want to have {
  "vzdveg643": {
    "lldistrict":"Ambilobe",
    "id_province": 7,
    "id":"vzdveg643"
  },
  "vzvsdv5327": {
    "lldistrict":"Ambilobe",
    "id_province": 7,
    "id":"vzvsdv5327"
  }
}

Comment: *to change the id of each object with the value of its key* <-- Again, this doesn't make sense. What is "it's key"? Each of your objects has 3 keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example you can just replace `"????????????????"` with `fokontany` which is already a key of each object.

```js
const fokontanys = {
  "vzdveg643": {
    "lldistrict":"Ambilobe",
    "id_province": 7,
    "id": null
  },
  "vzvsdv5327": {
    "lldistrict":"Ambilobe",
    "id_province": 7,
    "id": null
  }
}

const newFokontanys = {}

Object.keys(fokontanys).forEach(function (fokontany) { 
  fokontanys[fokontany].ll_district=fokontanys[fokontany].lldistrict;
  fokontanys[fokontany].id=fokontany;
  delete fokontanys[fokontany].lldistrict;
  newFokontanys[fokontany] = fokontanys[fokontany];
});

console.log(newFokontanys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.fromEntreis`, `Object.entries` and `map` to do in one-line

```js
const process = (data) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).map(([key, obj]) => [key, { ...obj, id: key }])
  );

const data = {
  vzdveg643: {
    lldistrict: "Ambilobe",
    id_province: 7,
    id: null,
  },
  vzvsdv5327: {
    lldistrict: "Ambilobe",
    id_province: 7,
    id: null,
  },
};

console.log(process(data))
```